# Assign id or class to fetched data to work with in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

i have fetched data from database with PHP in while loop.i want to assign id or class to this data to work with it in javaScript individually with every id or class which are in table td.

For example

```
$i = 0 ;
if($result->rowCount() > 0)
{
   while($row_pro = $prod->fetch())
   {
       $type = $row->type;
       $brand = $row->brand;
       $qty = $row->qty;
       $total = $row->total;
       $i++ ;
?>

<tr>
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $type; ?>" ></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $brand; ?>" ></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" ></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" ></td>
</tr>

<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: You can put the `<tr>` inside your while loop or you can select it manually from the array in each `<td>`.

Comment: tr is already in while loop,But how to select it manually from the array in each td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to simply echo out your loop's index (`$i`) as a class:

```
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $type; ?>" class="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $brand; ?>" class="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" class="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" class="<?php echo $i; ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

Keep in mind that you can't do this for IDs, as **[IDs must be unique](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)**. Also, you don't actually **need** to do this in the first place, as you can directly target elements with JavaScript that have neither IDs nor classes. This is most commonly with **[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**, which returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements. Here's an example of that:

```js
let three = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[2];
console.log(three.innerHTML);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @Obsidian Age actually i have further calculation of quantity and price in which every td is different from each other. and deal with every input individually.than it calculates sub total and discount from it.

Comment: and can i add this as id  id="type_'[i]' "

Comment: No problem! And yeah, you can target any element without an ID. Just give it the right index number in `getElementsByTagName()`. Classes / IDs would indeed make it easier though, and if you are prefixing the input name to the IDs per input (so that you end up with `id="type_1"` and `id="brand_1"`, then that is totally fine. Just don't end up with two `id="1"` cases, or your JavaScript will mysteriously stop working haha ;)

Comment: can you give an exmple, if i add this  id="type_1"  then how can i call it in javaScript.